# Python socketIO callback is lost: `Unknown callback received, ignoring.`

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I have a Flask-SocketIO server that connects with a number of python-socketIO clients. I want to know which clients are online. To get to know this, I am sending a `ping` event from the server with a callback function to process the response.

The structure of the server code is as follows:

```
class Server:
    def ping(self):
        while True:
            self.socketio.emit(
                'ping', namespace='/some_namespace', room='some_room',
                callback=self.pong_response
            )

    def pong_response(self, client_id):
        # goal: updates the client's status as online in a database
        print(client_id)
```

In the client application, we have:

```
from socketio import ClientNamespace

class SocketClient(ClientNamespace):
    def on_ping(self) -> int:
        return <my_id>
```

Now, when I run the server and client application locally, this works fine: the client responds to the server and I can print the ID sent by the client app.

However, when the server app is deployed (in our case to an Azure App Service), the server logs print:

```
socketio.server - WARNING  - Unknown callback received, ignoring.
```

I have no clue why this works locally but not when deployed in Azure. Also, is this a good approach to update which client are online?

---

Possibly relevant details:

- server is on `Flask-SocketIO==5.1.1`
- clients are on `python-socketio==5.5.0`
- Python 3.7
- On the server, the ping/pong is running in a separate thread

---

**Update**:
It seems the message queue (RabbitMQ) is causing the issue. When defining our socketIO connection we use:

```
socketio = SocketIO(
    self.app,
    async_mode='gevent_uwsgi',
    message_queue=msg_queue,
)
```

It works when `message_queue=None` is put in. However, this obviously does not fix our issue when we want to run multiple server instances. I have yet to figure out why this doesn't work and how I can fix it.

Comment: You are using threads for this? Are you using eventlet or gevent in this server? Are you aware of the complications that occur when mixing threads and greenlets?

Comment: Yes we are initiating the socket connection with `async_mode='gevent_uwsgi'`. I'll look into the complications, thanks for pointing me there.

Comment: We also have one client app running on an Azure VM and for that one the ping/pong works. No idea why, but also something to look into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research and eventually posting [this Github issue](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/1152#issuecomment-1466244872), the conclusion is that callbacks from multiple clients are not supported by python-socketio.

So since using callbacks is not an option to achieve this, I instead changed the code so that the clients send a ping to the server every N seconds (instead of the other way around). This way no callbacks are necessary.